# merge two pandas data frame and skip common columns of right

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas DataFrame as a lightweight dataset to maintain some status and need to dynamically/continuously merge new DataFrames into existing table. Say I have two datasets as below:

df1:

```
   a  b
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

df2:

```
    b   c
0  10  11
1  12  13
2  14  15
3  16  17
4  18  19
```

I want to merge df2 to df1 (on index), and for columns in common (in this case, it is 'b'), simply discard the common column of df2.

```
   a  b   c
0  0  1  11
1  2  3  13
2  4  5  15
3  6  7  17
4  8  9  19
```

My code was checking common part between df1 and df2 by using SET， so that I manually drop common part in df2. I wonder is there any much efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can simply use concat, pd.concat([df1, df2['c']], axis = 1)

Answer (score 8):

First identify the columns in `df2` not in `df1`

```
cols = df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)
```

Then `pd.DataFrame.join`

```
df1.join(df2[cols])

   a  b   c
0  0  1  11
1  2  3  13
2  4  5  15
3  6  7  17
4  8  9  19
```

Or `pd.concat` will also work

```
pd.concat([df1, df2[cols]], axis=1)

   a  b   c
0  0  1  11
1  2  3  13
2  4  5  15
3  6  7  17
4  8  9  19
```

Answer (score 6):

Pandas merge function will also work wonders. You can do it as:

```
pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, how='inner')

   a  b   c
0  0  1  11
1  2  3  13
2  4  5  15
3  6  7  17
4  8  9  19
```

by eliminating the 'on' attribute of merge function it will consider the columns which are in-common in both of the dataframes.